# Resolve peerDependencies warnings?

Tags: node.js, webpack

I have a React + WebPack project, when I install the npm dependencies I get some warnings about unsatisfied peerDependencies:

```
$ npm install
npm WARN carte-blanche@0.2.1 requires a peer of webpack@>=1 <3 but none was installed.
npm WARN carte-blanche-react-plugin@0.2.1 requires a peer of webpack@>=1 <3 but none was installed.
npm WARN carte-blanche-react-plugin@0.1.3 requires a peer of carte-blanche@^0.1.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN carte-blanche-react-plugin@0.1.3 requires a peer of webpack@>=1 <3 but none was installed.
npm WARN extract-text-webpack-plugin@1.0.1 requires a peer of webpack@^1.9.11 but none was installed.
npm WARN karma-webpack@1.7.0 requires a peer of webpack@^1.4.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN react-overlays@0.5.4 requires a peer of react-dom@^0.14.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN react-simpletabs@0.6.1 requires a peer of react@0.12.x - 1.x but none was installed.
```

Everything works as expected, but I get these warnings and I can't find a way to resolve them.

I have tried manually installing (for instance) webpack manually, but nothing changes at all.